# Hide the spinner on LWC after file download using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I used the below JS code to download a file. It makes the spinner visible using `loaded=false` but the line `loaded=true` doesn't make the spinner hide.

```
    handleResourceDownload(event) {
        this.loaded = false;
        const index = this.findResourceIndexById(event.target.name);
        const url = this.resources[index].contentDocLink;
        const fileName = this.resources[index].title;
        const mimeType = this.resources[index].mimeType;
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', url, true);
        x.responseType = 'blob';
        x.onload = function (e) {
            download(x.response, fileName, mimeType);
        };
        x.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
            this.loaded = true;
        });
        x.send();
    }
```

loaded is defined as `@track loaded = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the inner function, `this` (the lwc component reference) is not accessible inside that. If you replace that inner function with arrow function, this should work fine. An arrow function can access the variables from the parent block context.

Instead of

```
x.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
     this.loaded = true;
});
```

Use this

```
x.addEventListener("loadend", () => {
     this.loaded = true;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In the following code, `this` points to the XMLHTTPRequest object (i.e. `x`).

```
x.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
            this.loaded = true;
        });
```

If you examine this code during runtime, `this.loaded` will be undefined because its not the same `loaded` variable as declared in your LWC component. So, the `loaded` variable in your LWC component remains as false.

Solution to problem is to implement JS promise based request implementation. Follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Wrap the XMLHTTPRequest logic inside a function that returns a JS promise.
2. Call this wrapper function and put your logic to update the boolean value inside the `then` and `catch` blocks (that way it executes only after completion of the web request and you will be able to access the `loaded` variable declared in the LWC component).

Sample code given below:

```
handleResourceDownload(event) {
    this.loaded = false;
    const index = this.findResourceIndexById(event.target.name);
    const url = this.resources[index].contentDocLink;
    const fileName = this.resources[index].title;
    const mimeType = this.resources[index].mimeType;
    
    this.makeRequest('GET', url, fileName, mimeType)
    .then(function (response) {
        this.loaded = true;
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error('Augh, there was an error!', err.statusText);
    });
}

function makeRequest (method, url, fileName, mimeType) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        // Do whatever you need to do upon successful response here
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

[FYI:

- I'm setting the boolean flag only in the then block, but you might need handle in catch block too.
- makeRequest function provided below is just a sample and you will have to modify it according to your business logic.
- I was able to test only the update of boolean variable and the rest of the business logic needs to be implemented and tested by you (since, there is not enough details on what you want to do).

]

BTW, a better and cleaner way to implement web requests is to use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), which works leveraging JS promises.